# SVN merging with version 1.4

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

From what I have read, when merging SVN before 1.4 I have to do this "by hand" because the previous-merge info is not available:
svn merge svn://server/repo/trunk@revision svn://server/repoo/branch .

Since this is the first time I am merging what do I put in revision? Do I use the one at "branch time"?

Also, is there any way of doing this within the Eclipse-Collabnet client or do I have to do it via Tortoise?

Comment: You can put the first revision of the branch, or any other previous revision. But what do you want to merge and where? I'm not sure the comand you show is the right one.

Comment: I am trying to merge a branch into the trunk. The trunk is the main development line and the branch was created when we released a version. We made a number of fixes to the branch and now need to merge them back into the trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command to use is explained [in the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.commonuses.wholebr). Assuming you started your maintenance branch at revision 341, and the trunk is at revision 405, and the working copy is pointing to the trunk, the command should be:

svn merge -r 341:405 http://svn.example.com/repos/calc/branches/my-maintenance-branch

Remember that a merge consists in applying a diff from point A to point B into the working copy. Here, points A and points C are in the same branch: the maintenance branch: all the changes you made in this branch must be reapplied on the trunk.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to do this directly from within Eclipse?

Comment: No. I never use Eclipse's SVN support except for a diff or a revert sometimes. I find TortoiseSVN easier to use, and the fact that I can use it for anything and not just Eclipse projects makes it my SVN tool of choice. What I would do if I were you is upgrading to a newer version. 1.4 is really old, and much progres has been done since.

Comment: I need to talk to the person in charge of the SVN for that. Would upgrading now help or will I still need to do the command-line merge this time?

Comment: Upgrading would enable automatic merge tracking, among other useful things. You wouldn't have to track what has been merged and what hasn't been: SVN would do it for you.